# I just started using mysql and i have a syntax error its probably dumb but i cant see an error anywhere

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

i have been puzzling over where the incorrect syntax is but am unable to find it any help would be greatly appreciated

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE keys
    -> (
    -> id INT unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    -> frame INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    -> key VARCHAR(44)
    -> );
```

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'keys(id int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, frame INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, ke' at line 1

Comment: You shouldn't (or can't) use `key` as a column name, since it is a MySQL keyword. Change the name to something else.

Comment: When you ask on Stack Overflow for help with an error, please copy & paste the full text of the error message. Don't make us guess — help us to help you!

Comment: quote the identifiers with backticks. Make it a habit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`KEYS` and `KEY` are reserved keywords in MySQL.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-K

Either rename the table and the column to something that is not a reserved keyword, or else enclose the reserved words in back-ticks every time you use them.

```
CREATE TABLE `keys`
(
 id INT unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 frame INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 `key` VARCHAR(44)
);
```

But there's another problem with this table: an AUTO_INCREMENT column must be the first column of a primary key or unique key. You have made `frame` the primary key, and `id` is not part of any table key at all.